# Считается ли нормальным такой стиль написания кода?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

```
public class MainTest {
    PracticeWork1 grades;

    MainTest() {
        grades = new PracticeWork1();
        init();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainTest();
    }

    public void init() {
        testOut();
        grades.adder();
        testOut();
        grades.adder(98);
        testOut();
    }
}
```

пример 2

```
public class MyWin extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyWin() {
        Container c = getContentPane(); 
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

        Panel child= new Panel();    
        c.add(child);
        setTitle("Example window"); 

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true); // отображаем окно
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MyWin();
    }
}
```

Правильно ли в методе main создавать обьект того класса в котором этот мейн находиться , а не прописывать большинство логики в нём ?

Comment: что именно вас смущает?

Comment: Считается ли нормальным писать такой код ? т.к Конструктор по сути меняет свой смысл.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, он о том, можно ли помещать логику класса в конструктор.

Технически это возможно и будет работать, но с точки зрения смысла кода это не очень хорошо. Конструктор должен *конструировать* класс, а действие должно запускаться каким-либо *методом*.

Если ваш проект маленький, вы можете нарушить это правило (как и многие другие), но для более-менее серьёзного проекта я бы посоветовал оставлять в конструкторе лишь инициализацию.

Comment: Будет ли считаться правильным если в конструктор поместить , например, метод к котором сосредоточена логика программы . Если нет , то как будет правильно писать подобные программы ?

Comment: @ДмитрийЖеребко: По моему мнению — неправильно. В конструкторе инициализация, логика в методах.

Comment: @ДмитрийЖеребко: Чтобы вызывающий код выглядел как-то так: `Worker w = new Worker(); w.work();`.

Answer (score 3):

Логика в конструкторе - не очень хорошая идея. Такой код тяжело тестировать. Так же в случае возникновения исключения в конструкторе могут быть проблемы. Я бы рекомендовал инициализацию проводить не в конструкторе:

```
public class MainTest {
    PracticeWork1 grades;

    MainTest() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainTest test = new MainTest();
        test.init();
    }

    public void init() {
        grades = new PracticeWork1();
        testOut();
        grades.adder();
        testOut();
        grades.adder(98);
        testOut();
    }
}
```

Для этого хорошо подошёл бы шаблон [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).